# Handling 'Not Found' Responses in Supabase when Querying Vector Databases

Tags: typescript, database, supabase

Recently, I've been experimenting with a vector database. I've successfully inserted some data into it. However, what I want to achieve is implementing a 'not found' handling when there are no matching documents from the search query

I'm using TypeScript to run the Supabase client with the help of LangchainJS. Here is the code I've created.

```
const client = createClient(process.env.SUPABASE_URL, process.env.SUPABASE_PRIVATE_KEY, {
   auth: { persistSession: false },
});
const store = new SupabaseVectorStore(new OpenAIEmbeddings(), {
   client,
   tableName: 'documents'
});
const funcFilterA: SupabaseFilterRPCCall = (rpc) =>
   rpc
   .filter("metadata->b::int", "lt", 2)
   .filter("metadata->c::int", "gt", 8);
const searchResult = await store.similaritySearch(req.body.query, 1, funcFilterA);
console.log(searchResult);
```

And here is an example of the data I've inserted into those documents.

```
{
  pageContent: "Some content",
  metadata: { b: 1, c: 10, stuff: "right" },
}
```

When I perform a query with any question, it always displays the documents as they are in the database instead of providing a 'not found' result.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of your database function? It's probably configured in a way that always returns some results no matter how low the similarities are with any of the documents.